# summing array inside kernel doesn't work

Tags: cuda, sum

In the following code after loading the data to the shared array I am trying to sum the array in the shared memory. the loaded array size is 289 and following is my kernel with main.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "readmat.cuh"
//#include "mat.h"
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
//#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
using namespace std;
//using namespace cv;

typedef struct {
    size_t X;
    size_t Y;
    size_t U;
    size_t V;
    double* elements;
    int no_of_elements;
    int alpha;
} DataIn;


cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);




__device__ double getelementData(DataIn data, int x, int v, int u, int y)
{
    int index = data.X*data.Y*data.U*(v)+data.X*data.Y*(u)+data.X*(y)+x;
    return data.elements[index];
}

__global__ void universaladd(DataIn data,int alpha,double* imagedevice)
{
    int v = blockIdx.y;
    int u = blockIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y;
    int x = threadIdx.x;


    /*
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
    {
        if (u == 0)
            printf(" tooooooooooooooooootal       the vale got whenn u=%d  v=%d  is %f \n", u, v);
        if (v == 0)
            printf(" tooooooooooooooooootal       the vale got whenn u=%d  v=%d  is %f \n", u, v);

    }
    */
    double temp;
    int local_idx = (blockDim.y*threadIdx.x) + threadIdx.y;

    extern __shared__ double matrix[];

    int m = alpha - 1;
    int Y_shift = y*m;
    int X_shift = x*m;

    if (v < Y_shift && u < X_shift){
        matrix[data.Y*x + y] = getelementData(data, x, (data.V - (Y_shift - v)), (data.U - (X_shift - u)), y);
        temp = getelementData(data, x, (data.V - (Y_shift - v)), (data.U - (X_shift - u)), y);
        //printf("the vale got when y=%d x=%d u=%d v=%d is %f \n", y, x, u, v, temp);

    }


    else if (v >= Y_shift && u < X_shift){
        matrix[data.Y*x + y] = getelementData(data, x, (v - (Y_shift)), (data.U - (X_shift - u)), y);
        temp = getelementData(data, x, (v - (Y_shift)), (data.U - (X_shift - u)), y);
        //printf("the vale got when y=%d x=%d u=%d v=%d is %f\n ", y, x, u, v, temp);
    }

    else if (v < Y_shift &&  u >= X_shift){
        matrix[data.Y*x + y] = getelementData(data, x, (data.V - (Y_shift - v)), (u - (X_shift)), y);
        temp = getelementData(data, x, (data.V - (Y_shift - v)), (u - (X_shift)), y);
        //printf("the vale got when y=%d x=%d u=%d v=%d is %f \n", y, x, u, v, temp);
    }

    else if (v >= Y_shift && u >= X_shift){
        matrix[data.Y*x + y] = getelementData(data, x, (v - (Y_shift)), (u - (X_shift)), y);
        temp = getelementData(data, x, (v - (Y_shift)), (u - (X_shift)), y);
        //printf("the vale got when y=%d x=%d u=%d v=%d is %f \n", y, x, u, v, temp);
    }

    //if((u==0 && v==0) && (x>15 && y>15)) // for testing
    //printf("the vale got when y=%d x=%d u=%d v=%d is %f \n", y, x, u, v, temp);
    //printf("Maaaaaa the vale got when y=%d x=%d u=%d v=%d is %.1f \n", y, x, u, v, matrix[0]);

    __syncthreads;
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    /*
    //Section 1 for testing
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
    {
        for (int m = (data.X*data.Y) - 1; m > 0; m--)
        {
            matrix[0] += matrix[m];
        }
    }
    */
    /*
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
    {
        if (u < 5 && v <5)
            printf(" tooooooooooooooooootal       the vale got whenn u=%d  v=%d  is %f \n", u, v, matrix[data.Y*x + y]);

    }
    */
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //__syncthreads;
    ///*
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //sectiion 2 
    int different = (data.X*data.Y) - 256;
    if (local_idx < different-1)
    {
        printf("the value when x=%d y=%d u=%d v=%d  %d      %f to val %f is \n",x,y,u,v, local_idx, matrix[256 + local_idx], matrix[local_idx]);
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[256 + local_idx];
    }


    __syncthreads;



    if (local_idx < 128)
    {
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 128];

    }
    __syncthreads;
    if (local_idx < 64)
    {
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 64];

    }
    __syncthreads;
    if (local_idx < 32) {
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 32];
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 16];
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 8];
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 4];
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 2];
        matrix[local_idx] += matrix[local_idx + 1];
    }

    __syncthreads;
    if (local_idx == 0)
        imagedevice[data.V*u + v] = matrix[local_idx];

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    __syncthreads;
    //*/
    /*
    if (x == 0 && y == 0)
    {
        if (5>u && 5>v)
            printf(" tooooooooooooooooootal       the vale got whenn u=%d  v=%d  is %f \n", u, v, matrix[0]);

    }
    */
}

/*
__global__ void intergershift(DataIn data)
{
int v = threadIdx.x;
int u = threadIdx.y;
int y = blockIdx.x;

int Height = blockDim.y;
extern __shared__ double* dataShared[];
double *** dataPoint = (double***)&dataShared;
double *** dataPointShifted = (double***)&dataShared[data.V];
double ** dataElements = (double**)&dataShared[2 * data.V];
dataPoint[v] = &dataShared[2 * data.V + Height*v];


}*/
int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    time_t start, end;
    int elements;
    int numberofdimension;

    //const char *file = "Bracelet.mat";
    //const size_t* dimepointer;



    //readmat thismat(file);
    //numberofdimension = thismat.getnumbrofdimensions();
    //dimepointer = thismat.dimensionpointer();

    size_t X, Y, U, V;
    X = 17;
    Y = 17;
    U = 512;
    V = 320;
    // Dimensions end
    DataIn data;
    data.U = U;
    data.Y = Y;
    data.X = X;
    data.V = V;
    size_t size = X*Y*U*V*sizeof(double);
    data.no_of_elements = X*Y*U*V;
    cudaError_t status;
    double * dataarray = new double[X*Y*U*V];
    for (int k = 0; k < U*V*X*Y; k++)
        dataarray[k] = 225;
    short * Device_data;
    cout << "the size is" << sizeof(Device_data) << endl;
    status = cudaSetDevice(0);
    status = cudaMalloc((void**)&data.elements, size);
    status = cudaMemcpy(data.elements, dataarray, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (status != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory copyind original data failed");
        cudaFree(data.elements);
        //cudaFree(arrangeddata);

    }

    /*
    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
    cout << *(thismat.getarraypointer()+t)<<" ";
    cout << endl << "original data printed" << endl;;
    */
    double*  image = new double[U*V];
    double *imagedevice;
    status = cudaMalloc((void**)&imagedevice, sizeof(double)*U*V);

    //__global__ void universaladd(DataIn data,int alpha,double* imagedevice)
    dim3 dimBlock(data.X, data.Y);
    dim3 dimGrid(data.U, data.V);
    universaladd << <dimGrid, dimBlock, sizeof(double)*X*Y >> >(data, 1, imagedevice);


    status = cudaGetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, "Launch status: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(status));

    status = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching\n", status);




    status = cudaMemcpy(image, imagedevice, sizeof(double)*U*V, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (status != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory copyind original data failed");
        cudaFree(data.elements);
    }
        //cudaFree(arrangeddata);
        for (int t = 0; t < 15; t++)
            cout << image[t] << " ";
        cout << endl << "data printed device";
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
```

however here I am not getting the desired results. I tried the loop in section 1 and there the results are okay however kernel ends before executing all the threads. The device synchronization gives me error code 4. However before device synchronization there is no error relevant to the kernel launch.

When I am trying the code in section 2 there I don't get any sum correctly. There is no error message relevant to the kernel launch or device synchronization. However when that part tried in another code it work fine. Here the loaded data is pixel values from 1 to 255. Since the sums are correct when loop is used I don't think that problem is with the loaded data. Also here I have checked the values if they are out of 255 or negative. In console no thread loads value that is not in between 0 and 255 because there isn't any value printed in the console. The problem is not only getting the sum incorrectly but some value are abnormal. Here grid dimension is **320x512**(data.Uxdata.V) and block dimension is **17x17**(data.Xxdata.Y). so if values in the matrix[] is valid they maximum should be 255*289 however there are negative and very large values.I think problem is with reduction but I just can't figure what it is.

the output is

when launched with loop(section 1) section 2 is commented

```
    Launch status: no error
cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 0 after launching
65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025 65025
data printed device
```

Here memory copying from device to host is failed which I think due to kernel stopping before completing the task. However the values printed inside kernel are correct when I checked them against matlab.

**[UPDATE]** Here after increasing WDDM TDR delay loop runs fine and value are correct but section 2 still doesn't give the desired results.since section2 runs fine with just a array that is launched with 1 1D block and 1xsize threads i think problem is related to incompatibility of launch configuration with reduction.

When launched with array reduction section 1 is commented

```
Launch status: no error
cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code 0 after launching
85275 7650 27675 58500 27450 103050 30375 17775 18000 12825 24750 95625 15975 68175 7425
```

here there is no error regarding copying image from device to host

**[edit]**

This is the kernel with main. Earlier I was loading data from mat file and now I have filled the data with 225 value.

Comment: nobody can help you without an [MCVE]

Comment: @talonmies thank you for pointing me out that. I have updated my question.

Comment: i don't see how your edit helps. You need to produce the shortest, simplest example someone else could compile and run.

Comment: @talomies I have added the main function. the problem was I was importing data from mat file.

Answer (score 1):

At last I found the problem. The problems was because of lack of synchronization. I was calling  __syncthreads; in wrong way. It should be **__syncthreads();**,not __syncthreads;